Solving inequalities involving multiple absolute values and a single variable x: why do we split all x-values into three intervals?
To brush up on some of my algebra and trigonometry I am currently working through Sheldon Axler's "Algebra and Trigonometry".
When finding the solution sets to (in)equalities involving multiple absolute values with the same variable appearing in both absolute values, I am a bit confused as to why we proceed by splitting up the set of real numbers into three intervals in order to find our solution set. To give an example, take the following equation:
|x − 3| + |x − 4| = 9.
Since the absolute values function maps negative numbers to their additive inverse, and positive numbers (and 0) to themselves, we have four different options depending on the values of our inputs:
(1) x − 3 > 0 and x − 4 > 0;
(2) x − 3 > 0 and x − 4 < 0;
(3) x − 3 < 0 and x − 4 > 0;
(4) x − 3 < 0 and x − 4 < 0.
Now, we examine whether the different intervals has any solutions and take the union of the intervals in which our equation above is satisfied as our solution set.
However, in Axler's book, and many YouTube videos I have found on solving (in)equalities involving absolute values, it seems that the instructor only considers three different intervals instead of four (as above) - Axler, for example, suggests to use the intervals (−∞, 3), [3, 4], and (4, ∞) for the above equation. Eddie Woo also says we only have to examine three intervals when solving (in)equalities like the one above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAv73B4QvI4&t=0s. What is the idea behind picking three intervals as opposed to four (as I have a hard time grasping the why behind it) and how do we pick these three intervals in a non-arbitrary way, and is there some general neat method for finding these three intervals?
Thanks in advance!

In general the multiple intervals will be contradictory and possibly redundant. Obviouslly case 3 where $x-3 < 0$ but $x-4>0$ is impossible as $x-4 < x-3$.  To be more efficient, the other method notes that as $x$ spans the real numbers to note when the components swith signs.  That happens firs when $x=3$ and then when $x=4$.

The way to think of this is that the "critical" points occur when one of the blocks turns to zero.  There are two blocks, so there are two such numbers, those two "critical" numbers break the number line into three segment, all the numbers below the lower numbers, all the numbers between the two numbers, and all the numbers greater than the larger number.

Thank you for the response! It makes more sense to me now, but I'm still confused as to exactly why we can get away with only checking three intervals instead of four intervals, in general, when we are solving absolute value (in) equalities like above? Is it always going to be the case that we are going to have redundant intervals and/or conditions for intervals that no number can satisfy? Because if not, then can we not end up in a situation where we miss a solution(s) to our equation or inequality?

" but I'm still confused as to exactly why we can get away with only checking three intervals instead of four intervals"  And what is the fourth interval?  Consider your four cases:  1) $x-3>0$ and $x-4> 0$.  That is $x>4>3$ or $(4,\infty)$. that's the first interval.  Case 2) $x-3>0$ and $x-4< 0$.  That is $3<x < 4$.  or $(3,4)$. That's the second.  Case 3) $x-3<0$ and $x-4<0$>  That if $4<x <3$ or $(4,3)={x\in \mathbb R| x<3$ and $x>4}$. That's the empty set.  It is not an interval at all. and Case 4: $x-4<0$ and $x-3< 0$ or $x< 3 < 4$.  That is $(-\infty,3)$ That's a third interval.

"Is it always going to be the case that we are going to have redundant intervals and/or conditions for intervals that no number can satisfy?" Not always of course.  But in the real numbers (which has order) we are going to get a certain number of critical points that can be placed in order, and the intervals between this points is everything and all that exists.  There is no need to check anything else.  If you have $a<b$ and $b<x<a$ there no need to check that as that can never happen.

Well the first one is $$x>3 \wedge x>4 \implies x>4$$
The second one is valid, and can be written together as $$3<x<4$$
The third and fourth one is impossible
$$x<3 \wedge 4<x$$ is not possible
Fourth one should have been $x-3<0 \wedge x-4<0$ can be again written singly as $$x<3$$
Here $"\wedge"$ means logical AND
$$\text{ Edit:-My approach of thinking about this }$$
Let $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x-a_i|=k\\i<j \implies a_i<a_j$$
If we draw a graph,we would see certain critical points at $a_1,a_2,...a_n$,which are points at which this function is not differentiable, as their slopes change after each of these points.
Say for $|x-a_1|+|x-a_2|+|x-a_3|$, before $x$ approaches $a_1$, we get $-(x-a_1)-(x-a_2)-(x-a_3)=a_1+a_2+a_3-3x$, but after this when $a_1<x<a_2$, we get $(x-a_1)-(x-a_2)-(x-a_3)=-a_1+a_2+a_3-x$. So we clearly see the change in the equation of the line.
Our main targets are the critical points, as these are points where the equations change. Thus for $n$ critical points,we have $n+1$ regions to check.  In the example I used, we have to check $4$ regions, $x<a_1,a_1<x<a_2,a_2<x<a_3,a_3<x$
Few more tricks are that,
The equation of the line for $x\in(a_i,a_{i+1})$ is the negative of the equation of the line for $x\in(a_{n-i},a_{n+1-i})$.
If $n$ is even,and $a_i$ are in an arithmetic progression, then for $x\in(a_{\frac n2},a_{\frac n2 +1})$,$f(x)$ is constant and has a minimum value which is equal to that of $f(a_{\frac n2})=f(a_{\frac n2 +1})$
If $n$ is odd,then minimum value is $f(a_{\frac{n+1}{2}})$ which occurs at a single point

Thanks for the response and the correction! This is also what I have been doing thus far. But, is there any way of reducing the intervals we have to check to just three from the get go? (here I am not just thinking of the equation I listed about, but in general) And what would be the method of doing is? Or should I just proceed as you did here every time I want to solve an (in)equality as the one I mentioned, and then eliminate all impossible combinations and reduce the options that way?

@fdluuuigo314 I'm writing your answer in my question

Too long for a comment but:
Suppose instead of $2$ moduli you had four.  I'm making this up as I type.  Suppose you wanted to solve $|x-3| + |x+4| = |5x-7| + |9-x| + 13$.
If we consider when each are positive of negative we will have $2^4 = 16$ cases.  That is WAY too many to deal with.  Especially when I tell you I know for certain (SPOILER ALERT!) that $11$ of them will be inconsistent and impossible.  That's $11$ out of $16$ unnecessary impossibilities.  $68\%$ failure!  Bad track record.
Instead... we can consider the critical points where each modulus is equal to $0$.  There will be $4$ such points.  Those divide the real number line into five segments to check.
The points are: $3,-4, \frac 75, 9$ or in order $-4, \frac 75, 3,9$ and divide the cases to consider as

$x<-4$ so $x-3,x+4,5x-7$ are all negative and $9-x$ is positive.

$4 < x<\frac 75$ so $x-3,5x-7$ are negative and $9-x,x+4$ are positive.

$\frac 75 < x < 3$ so $x-3$ is negative and $9-x,x+4,5x-7$ are positive.

$3< x < 9$ so all are positive, and

$x>9$ so that $9-x$ is negative and $x-3,x+4,5x-7$ are positive.


All the eleven other cases, such as $x-3,9-x$ are positive $x+4, 5x -7$ are negative, or all are negative are self contradictory, can never happen, and can be (and should be) ignored.  For example: if $x-3$ and $9-x$ but $x+4$ and $5x-7$ are negative then we must have $x>3$ and $x<9$ and $x<-4$ and $x<\frac 75$ which is impossible.  Likewise all being negative requires both $x<-4$ and $x > 9$.  And so on.

The third one is not possible (as it says $x>4$ yet $x<3$). Let us look at another example:
$$|x-1|+|x-2|+|x-3|=5$$
You would want to make $2\times2\times2=8$ cases. But you know that there will be cases like $x>2$ and $x<1$ again. The point is, once $x>3$, it is forced that $x>2$ and $x>1$. So, you would think this way:

If $x>3$, then $x-3$, $x-2$, $x-1$ are all positive.
If $x<3$, then $x-3<0$. What now? Is $x>2$? If yes, then $x-2$ and $x-1$ are positive.
If $x<2$, then $x-3$ and $x-2$ are negative. Just look at $x>1$ and $x<1$.

And so, you are only faced with four cases (and that is exhaustive, because of the way we obtained these cases).
In general, for an equation that has
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|x-a_i|$$
First, order the $a_i$s into $b_i$s, i.e. $b_1$, $\dots$, $b_n$ is just the sorted version of $a_1$, $\dots$, $a_n$. Then,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|x-a_i|=\sum_{i=1}^n|x-b_i|$$
Then, your cases will just be $x>b_n$, $b_n>x>b_{n-1}$, $\dots$, $b_2>x>b_1$ and $x<b_1$.
Hope this helps. :)
